# PHP post request data retrieval using Jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have recently been trying to get back information from php using Jquery's ajax function Sending an the request works fine but receiving the information does not. I would appreciate the assistance.

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({                    
  url: 'sendEmail.php',     
  type: 'post', // performing a POST request
  data: values,
  dataType: 'json',                   
  success: function(result)         
  {
    console.log("check");//code does not come here
    if(result=="Success"){
        alert("Your message has been sent. I will get in touch with you soon");
    }
    else{
        alert("Umm.. The meesage was not sent :(. You can still contact me on myemail@gmail.com");
    }

  } 
});
```

The php:

```
<?php
   $recipient = 'myemail@gmail.com';
   $subject = "Portfolio Message";
   $fromName = stripslashes($_POST['Name']);
   $fromEmail= stripcslashes($_POST['Email']);
   $msg = "Message from: $fromMessage\nEmail: $fromEmail\n\n".stripslashes($_POST['Message']);



   if (mail($recipient, $subject, $msg)){
       echo "Success";
   }
   else {
       echo "Fail";
   }
?>
```

Comment: because the type you send back is not json try echo like this `echo json_encode(array(
                            'error' => false,
                            'message' => "Success"
                        ));` and in your succes get the data as `result.message`

Comment: Or if you want you can just change the `dataType` into `text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem:

The response type didn't match the dataType expected by ajax

To solve you have two option:

1. Change your dataType into text
2. Send back a proper json response

Either of the two will solve your problem example of sending json is to encode the response in `json_encode`

Answer (score 1):

```
dataType: 'json',
```

That needs a json reply from PHP, add in your php code the headers.

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   $recipient = 'myemail@gmail.com';
   $subject = "Portfolio Message";
   $fromName = stripslashes($_POST['Name']);
   $fromEmail= stripcslashes($_POST['Email']);
   $msg = "Message from: $fromMessage\nEmail: $fromEmail\n\n".stripslashes($_POST['Message']);

   if (mail($recipient, $subject, $msg)){
       echo json_encode("Success");
   }
   else {
       echo json_encode("Fail");
   }
?>
```